# Duplicate Redirect Page but Alter Content Type

Tags: 2013, content-type, page-layout, redirect

I need a page just like the Redirect Page, but I need it to have a different content type.  This new content type uses Redirect Page as it's parent but includes some new columns that are used for organizing the pages in a view.

I've created the new content type, and creating a normal page layout is no problem.  What I can't figure out is how to make a page that works just like the redirect page, but using the alternate content type.

Answer (score 0):

The whole secret behind the Redirect page is the actual Page layout, not the content type itself (unless you count the association). What I'm practically saying is that you can create any content type deriving from any of the default Page content types and associate with it a new Page Layout.

Every time you switch to your content type also the Page layout gets applied and code within the actual .aspx would get executed - basically you could use META tag, or simply JavaScript, or if you have some Server-side logic even the plain ASP.NET code.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, it just seemed like the easiest thing to do would be use the existing asp.net tag '<PublishingWebControls:RedirectControl SecondsBeforeRedirect="5" runat="server"/>' that is used in the redirect page.  Using the snippets editor it doesn't like me when I try to add this to my page...

Comment: Yes, you're right in your assumptions. This however being a Server-Side control unless the Snippets support it, you would need to update the layout after being done with it, not via the HTML